# Picasso failed to load images in android kitkat

Tags: android, image, listview, picasso, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using Picasso to download images I get from a web service that I display in a listview.
It works fine on devices running above kitkat 5+.
In kitkat it fails to load some images.

My config is set like below

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24


 }
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
}
```

I'm calling Picasso in my listAdapter

```
 Picasso.with(main)
                .load(main.articles.get(position).image)
                .into(holder.image);
```

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fff"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/articleimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/articleimage"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="#ff48b0"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#3D3838"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="33dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/articleimage"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:id="@+id/excerpt"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:textColor="#4c4d4e"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my logs

```
Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err: com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$ResponseException: 404 Not Found
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.UrlConnectionDownloader.load(UrlConnectionDownloader.java:96)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:47)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-11 06:30:19.406 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)

 "Picasso-/wp-content/uploads/Vous-consommez-chaque-jour-cet-aliment-qui-endommage-votre-cerveau-et-votre-foie.jpg" prio=5 tid=613 RUNNABLE
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb20862a8 self=0xb98f6fd0
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=18174 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1186417376
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=1 core=0
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:613)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:589)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:142)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-11 06:52:44.326 28898-18174/com.s I/dalvikvm:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)



08-11 06:52:44.346 28898-18174/com.s D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false

08-11 06:52:44.366 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: ===============BEGIN PICASSO STATS ===============
08-11 06:52:44.366 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err: Memory Cache Stats
08-11 06:52:44.366 28898-28898/com.ss W/System.err:   Max Cache Size: 9586980
08-11 06:52:44.366 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Cache Size: 0
08-11 06:52:44.366 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Cache % Full: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Cache Hits: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Cache Misses: 1
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err: Network Stats
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Download Count: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Total Download Size: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Average Download Size: 0




08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err: Bitmap Stats
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Total Bitmaps Decoded: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Total Bitmap Size: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Total Transformed Bitmaps: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Total Transformed Bitmap Size: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Average Bitmap Size: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:   Average Transformed Bitmap Size: 0
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err: ===============END PICASSO STATS ===============
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:180)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:613)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:589)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:142)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:     at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
08-11 06:52:44.376 28898-28898/com.s W/System.err:  ... 6 more
```

Comment: please post the layout xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this and print exception

[image]

```
 Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
});
builder.build().load(URL).into(imageView);
```

Comment: I can access the ressource from a web browser

Comment: @sinfils can you send your image url